# How to find duplicate files with same name but in different case that exist in same directory in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, find, filesystems

How can I return a list of files that are named duplicates i.e. have same name but in different case that exist in the *same directory*?

I don't care about the contents of the files. I just need to know the location and name of any files that have a duplicate of the same name.

Example duplicates:

```
/www/images/taxi.jpg
/www/images/Taxi.jpg
```

Ideally I need to search all files recursively from a base directory. In above example it was `/www/`

Comment: what if you have same name but all in lowercase and all in different folders? which one you gonna delete?

Comment: @ghost: but in different case that exist _in the same folder_.

Comment: As pointed out by @paxdiablo I only care about named duplicates that exist in same folder.

Comment: but you said ideally you need to search recursively? or am i missing something?

Comment: @ghostdog74 I want to search for named duplicates that exist in the same folder. But I want to perform a search for new duplicates in every folder and sub folder.

I'm basically looking for any files that duplicated in the same location across an entire filesystem tree.

Comment: @Camsoft, have a rethink about which answer you want as accepted. The answer by @Christoffer Hammarström is a lot more elegant than mine and does exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The other answer is great, but instead of the "rather monstrous" perl script i suggest

```
perl -pe 's!([^/]+)$!lc $1!e'
```

Which will lowercase just the filename part of the path.

Edit 1: In fact the entire problem can be solved with:

```
find . | perl -ne 's!([^/]+)$!lc $1!e; print if 1 == $seen{$_}++'
```

---

Edit 3: I found a solution using sed, sort and uniq that also will print out the duplicates, but it only works if there are no whitespaces in filenames:

```
find . |sed 's,\(.*\)/\(.*\)$,\1/\2\t\1/\L\2,'|sort|uniq -D -f 1|cut -f 1
```

---

Edit 2: And here is a longer script that will print out the names, it takes a list of paths on stdin, as given by `find`. Not so elegant, but still:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;

my %dup_series_per_dir;
while (<>) {
    my ($dir, $file) = m!(.*/)?([^/]+?)$!;
    push @{$dup_series_per_dir{$dir||'./'}{lc $file}}, $file;
}

for my $dir (sort keys %dup_series_per_dir) {
    my @all_dup_series_in_dir = grep { @{$_} > 1 } values %{$dup_series_per_dir{$dir}};
    for my $one_dup_series (@all_dup_series_in_dir) {
        print "$dir\{" . join(',', sort @{$one_dup_series}) . "}\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: +1. I would strongly suggest accepting *this one* as the answer (instead of my currently accepted answer). It's far more elegant. My final version's a monstrosity since I came at it from a pipeline viewpoint and had to add perl to get around a problem with tr. This answer is proof positive that you can often get far better solutions by stepping back and starting again.

Comment: And use "find -type f" if you want it restricted to regular files(no directories).

Comment: Would be useful if the script displayed both offending files.

Comment: If you have multiple sub-directories to look for files with same name: `find . |xargs -n 1 basename| perl -ne 's!([^/]+)$!lc $1!e; print if 1 == $seen{$_}++'`

Comment: @PeterSenna: Or just `find . | perl -ne 's!.*/([^/]+)!lc $1!se; print if 1 == $seen{$_}++'`

Comment: @ChristofferHammarström: thanks a lot. It helped. It has but one weakness. For names that already contain a comma the output cannot be used as is. In case you wonder, that's the case for RCS files in a CVS repo, where case-sensitivity matters on *nix, but creates trouble on Windows. But it's a small price to pay. Tack så mycket!

Comment: @0xC0000022L: So use something else instead of a comma?

Answer (score 38):

Try:

```
ls -1 | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]' | sort | uniq -c | grep -v " 1 "
```

Simple, really :-) Aren't pipelines wonderful beasts?

The `ls -1` gives you the files one per line, the `tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]'` converts all uppercase to lowercase, the `sort` sorts them (surprisingly enough), `uniq -c` removes subsequent occurrences of duplicate lines whilst giving you a count as well and, finally, the `grep -v " 1 "` strips out those lines where the count was one.

When I run this in a directory with one "duplicate" (I copied `qq` to `qQ`), I get:

```
2 qq
```

For the "this directory and every subdirectory" version, just replace `ls -1` with `find .` or `find DIRNAME` if you want a specific directory starting point (`DIRNAME` is the directory name you want to use).

This returns (for me):

```
2 ./.gconf/system/gstreamer/0.10/audio/profiles/mp3
2 ./.gconf/system/gstreamer/0.10/audio/profiles/mp3/%gconf.xml
2 ./.gnome2/accels/blackjack
2 ./qq
```

which are caused by:

```
pax> ls -1d .gnome2/accels/[bB]* .gconf/system/gstreamer/0.10/audio/profiles/[mM]* [qQ]?
.gconf/system/gstreamer/0.10/audio/profiles/mp3
.gconf/system/gstreamer/0.10/audio/profiles/MP3
.gnome2/accels/blackjack
.gnome2/accels/Blackjack
qq
qQ
```

---

*Update:*

Actually, on further reflection, the `tr` will lowercase *all* components of the path so that both of

```
/a/b/c
/a/B/c
```

will be considered duplicates *even though they're in different directories*.

If you only want duplicates within a single directory to show as a match, you can use the (rather monstrous):

```
perl -ne '
    chomp;
    @flds = split (/\//);
    $lstf = $f[-1];
    $lstf =~ tr/A-Z/a-z/;
    for ($i =0; $i ne $#flds; $i++) {
        print "$f[$i]/";
    };
    print "$x\n";'
```

in place of:

```
tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]'
```

What it does is to only lowercase the final portion of the pathname rather than the whole thing. In addition, if you only want regular files (no directories, FIFOs and so forth), use `find -type f` to restrict what's returned.

Comment: Wow. That is one impressive command. Can't imagine ever being able to do that in Windows. I love *nix. Thank you so much.

Comment: You can do that on Windows just fine. Get yourself a copy of Cygwin or MinGW and enjoy :-)

Comment: But you can't do it out of the box.

Comment: @paxdiablo could you edit your post as I accidentally removed my vote and now it won't let me re-vote unless the post is edited.

Comment: great answer, but 1 tiny suggestion for optimization: I think you don't need "-1" on ls if you're redirecting into a pipe.

Comment: Actually, @Carl, I didn't realise that. I'm sure that never used to be the case with the older UNIXes, they would faithfully output the same to a pipe as to a tty. I suspect this changed in Linux. That could actually be rather annoying if you didn't expect it.

Comment: On the off chance that multiple matching files have filenames containining " 1 ", you should use `grep -v "^ *1"`

Comment: People that put spaces in their file names should be beaten to death with a wet celery stick (to make the pain last longer). :-)

Comment: Has anyone tried this using cygwin?  I'm not having luck with it, but I have a windows box with a large directory with many many sub directories and need to search for dups...  I loaded up cygwin thinking linux/unix scripting would be more beenficial than bat scripting

Comment: @ProfessionalAmateur, What do you mean by not working? Is it generating an error? Taking too long? Something else? And which part? I ask because most of my scripts are actually _done_ in CygWin (and tested later under Ubuntu if necessary).

Comment: @paxdiablo - Sorry I should have clarified.  It's not returning any results.  I hit enter and it just goes to the next prompt entry line, doesn't find any dups (I even manually created a dup just as a test).

Comment: This solution worked wonders for me, thank you! I did however have to adapt it slightly. I used the `find` command but it seems that the directory paths were causing the duplicates to not be found correctly, and so I added another pipe to the command, using `awk` to remove the directory path from the found records, so my final command looked like this:
 `find . -type f | awk -F/ '{print $NF}' | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]' |  sort | uniq -c | grep -v " 1 "` Do however bear in mind that this will ONLY list duplicate file names, not their directories and you wont be able to pipe to remove them etc.

Answer (score 6):

I believe

```
ls | sort -f | uniq -i -d
```

is simpler, faster, and will give the same result

Comment: Yes, for the current directory. But how about subdirectories? Note that you can only ignore case for the basename, not the entire path.

Comment: On Mac OSX if you have non-ASCII characters you may need to set the character encoding with `export LC_ALL='C'`

Comment: for subdirectories add the -R switch to ls

Answer (score 4):

Following up on the response of mpez0, to detect recursively just replace "ls" by "find .".
The only problem I see with this is that if this is a directory that is duplicating, then you have 1 entry for each files in this directory. Some human brain is required to treat the output of this.

But anyway, you're not automatically deleting these files, are you?

```
find . | sort -f | uniq -i -d
```

Comment: This is possibly a comment more than an answer, seems to be asking clarifying questions.

Answer (score 2):

This is a nice little command line app called `findsn` you get if you compile `fslint` that the deb package does not include.

it will find any files with the same name, and its lightning fast and it can handle different case.

```
/findsn --help
find (files) with duplicate or conflicting names.
Usage: findsn [-A -c -C] [[-r] [-f] paths(s) ...]
```

If no arguments are supplied the $PATH is searched for any redundant
or conflicting files.

```
-A  reports all aliases (soft and hard links) to files.
    If no path(s) specified then the $PATH is searched.
```

If only path(s) specified then they are checked for duplicate named
files. You can qualify this with -C to ignore case in this search.
Qualifying with -c is more restrictive as only files (or directories)
in the same directory whose names differ only in case are reported.
I.E. -c will flag files & directories that will conflict if transfered
to a case insensitive file system. Note if -c or -C specified and
no path(s) specified the current directory is assumed.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example how to find all duplicate jar files:

```
find . -type f -printf "%f\n" -name "*.jar" | sort -f | uniq -i -d
```

Replace `*.jar` with whatever duplicate file type you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a script that worked for me ( I am not the author). the original and discussion can be found here:
http://www.daemonforums.org/showthread.php?t=4661

```
#! /bin/sh

# find duplicated files in directory tree
# comparing by file NAME, SIZE or MD5 checksum
# --------------------------------------------
# LICENSE(s): BSD / CDDL
# --------------------------------------------
# vermaden [AT] interia [DOT] pl
# http://strony.toya.net.pl/~vermaden/links.htm

__usage() {
  echo "usage: $( basename ${0} ) OPTION DIRECTORY"
  echo "  OPTIONS: -n   check by name (fast)"
  echo "           -s   check by size (medium)"
  echo "           -m   check by md5  (slow)"
  echo "           -N   same as '-n' but with delete instructions printed"
  echo "           -S   same as '-s' but with delete instructions printed"
  echo "           -M   same as '-m' but with delete instructions printed"
  echo "  EXAMPLE: $( basename ${0} ) -s /mnt"
  exit 1
  }

__prefix() {
  case $( id -u ) in
    (0) PREFIX="rm -rf" ;;
    (*) case $( uname ) in
          (SunOS) PREFIX="pfexec rm -rf" ;;
          (*)     PREFIX="sudo rm -rf"   ;;
        esac
        ;;
  esac
  }

__crossplatform() {
  case $( uname ) in
    (FreeBSD)
      MD5="md5 -r"
      STAT="stat -f %z"
      ;;
    (Linux)
      MD5="md5sum"
      STAT="stat -c %s"
      ;;
    (SunOS)
      echo "INFO: supported systems: FreeBSD Linux"
      echo
      echo "Porting to Solaris/OpenSolaris"
      echo "  -- provide values for MD5/STAT in '$( basename ${0} ):__crossplatform()'"
      echo "  -- use digest(1) instead for md5 sum calculation"
      echo "       $ digest -a md5 file"
      echo "  -- pfexec(1) is already used in '$( basename ${0} ):__prefix()'"
      echo
      exit 1
    (*)
      echo "INFO: supported systems: FreeBSD Linux"
      exit 1
      ;;
  esac
  }

__md5() {
  __crossplatform
  :> ${DUPLICATES_FILE}
  DATA=$( find "${1}" -type f -exec ${MD5} {} ';' | sort -n )
  echo "${DATA}" \
    | awk '{print $1}' \
    | uniq -c \
    | while read LINE
      do
        COUNT=$( echo ${LINE} | awk '{print $1}' )
        [ ${COUNT} -eq 1 ] && continue
        SUM=$( echo ${LINE} | awk '{print $2}' )
        echo "${DATA}" | grep ${SUM} >> ${DUPLICATES_FILE}
      done

  echo "${DATA}" \
    | awk '{print $1}' \
    | sort -n \
    | uniq -c \
    | while read LINE
      do
        COUNT=$( echo ${LINE} | awk '{print $1}' )
        [ ${COUNT} -eq 1 ] && continue
        SUM=$( echo ${LINE} | awk '{print $2}' )
        echo "count: ${COUNT} | md5: ${SUM}"
        grep ${SUM} ${DUPLICATES_FILE} \
          | cut -d ' ' -f 2-10000 2> /dev/null \
          | while read LINE
            do
              if [ -n "${PREFIX}" ]
              then
                echo "  ${PREFIX} \"${LINE}\""
              else
                echo "  ${LINE}"
              fi
            done
        echo
      done
  rm -rf ${DUPLICATES_FILE}
  }

__size() {
  __crossplatform
  find "${1}" -type f -exec ${STAT} {} ';' \
    | sort -n \
    | uniq -c \
    | while read LINE
      do
        COUNT=$( echo ${LINE} | awk '{print $1}' )
        [ ${COUNT} -eq 1 ] && continue
        SIZE=$( echo ${LINE} | awk '{print $2}' )
        SIZE_KB=$( echo ${SIZE} / 1024 | bc )
        echo "count: ${COUNT} | size: ${SIZE_KB}KB (${SIZE} bytes)"
        if [ -n "${PREFIX}" ]
        then
          find ${1} -type f -size ${SIZE}c -exec echo "  ${PREFIX} \"{}\"" ';'
        else
          # find ${1} -type f -size ${SIZE}c -exec echo "  {}  " ';'  -exec du -h "  {}" ';'
          find ${1} -type f -size ${SIZE}c -exec echo "  {}  " ';'
        fi
        echo
      done
  }

__file() {
  __crossplatform
  find "${1}" -type f \
    | xargs -n 1 basename 2> /dev/null \
    | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]' \
    | sort -n \
    | uniq -c \
    | sort -n -r \
    | while read LINE
      do
        COUNT=$( echo ${LINE} | awk '{print $1}' )
        [ ${COUNT} -eq 1 ] && break
        FILE=$( echo ${LINE} | cut -d ' ' -f 2-10000 2> /dev/null )
        echo "count: ${COUNT} | file: ${FILE}"
        FILE=$( echo ${FILE} | sed -e s/'\['/'\\\['/g -e s/'\]'/'\\\]'/g )
        if [ -n "${PREFIX}" ]
        then
          find ${1} -iname "${FILE}" -exec echo "  ${PREFIX} \"{}\"" ';'
        else
          find ${1} -iname "${FILE}" -exec echo "  {}" ';'
        fi
        echo
      done 
  }

# main()

[ ${#} -ne 2  ] && __usage
[ ! -d "${2}" ] && __usage

DUPLICATES_FILE="/tmp/$( basename ${0} )_DUPLICATES_FILE.tmp"

case ${1} in
  (-n)           __file "${2}" ;;
  (-m)           __md5  "${2}" ;;
  (-s)           __size "${2}" ;;
  (-N) __prefix; __file "${2}" ;;
  (-M) __prefix; __md5  "${2}" ;;
  (-S) __prefix; __size "${2}" ;;
  (*)  __usage ;;
esac
```

If the find command is not working for you, you may have to change it. For example

```
OLD :   find "${1}" -type f | xargs -n 1 basename 
NEW :   find "${1}" -type f -printf "%f\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
find -type f  -exec readlink -m {} \; | gawk 'BEGIN{FS="/";OFS="/"}{$NF=tolower($NF);print}' | uniq -c
```

Where:

- `find -type f`
  recursion print all file's full path.
- `-exec readlink -m {} \;`
  get file's absolute path
- `gawk 'BEGIN{FS="/";OFS="/"}{$NF=tolower($NF);print}'`
  replace the all filename's to lower case
- `uniq -c`
  unique the path, -c output the count of duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Little bit late to this one, but here's the version I went with:

```
find . -type f | awk -F/ '{print $NF}' | sort -f | uniq -i -d
```

Here we are using:

1. **`find`** - find all files under the current dir
2. **`awk`** - remove the file path part of the filename
3. **`sort`** - sort case insensitively
4. **`uniq`** - find the dupes from what makes it through the pipe

*(Inspired by @mpez0 answer, and @SimonDowdles comment on @paxdiablo answer.)*

Answer (score 0):

You can check duplicates in a given directory with GNU awk:

```
gawk 'BEGINFILE {if ((seen[tolower(FILENAME)]++)) print FILENAME; nextfile}' *
```

This uses [BEGINFILE](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/BEGINFILE_002fENDFILE.html) to perform some action before going on and reading a file. In this case, it keeps track of the names that have appeared in an array `seen[]` whose indexes are the names of the files in lowercase.

If a name has already appeared, no matter its case, it prints it. Otherwise, it just jumps to the next file.

---

See an example:

```
$ tree
.
├── bye.txt
├── hello.txt
├── helLo.txt
├── yeah.txt
└── YEAH.txt

0 directories, 5 files
$ gawk 'BEGINFILE {if ((a[tolower(FILENAME)]++)) print FILENAME; nextfile}' *
helLo.txt
YEAH.txt
```

Answer (score -2):

I just used fdupes on CentOS to clean up a whole buncha duplicate files...

```
yum install fdupes
```