# Find empty files and their duplicates (partners)

Tags: bash, awk, duplicates, find

I am trying to train tesseract. The process involves creating triples of files: box files, text files and image (tif) files.

The tool that creates the .box files sometimes creates empty files. Those empty files cause problems for the engine.  So, I want to delete the empty box files as well as their partners.

The whole pattern looks like the following

- File1.box
- File1.gt.txt
- File1.tif
- File2.box
- File2.gt.txt
- File2.tif

File2.box is an empty file (has zero size). I want to find and delete it as well as its  partners (duplicates) such as File2.gt.txt and File2.tif.

Is this doable?

Comment: What have you tried ? What is not working in your attempt ?

Comment: Try starting with `for f in File*.box ; do echo $f; done`

Comment: I tried the commands available here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109056/how-to-find-duplicate-files-with-same-name-but-in-different-case-that-exist-in-s. But, finding the empty file has been very difficult to me.

Comment: Try adding in `if [ ! -s "$f" ] ; then echo $f; fi`

Comment: Did you try using the `find` command? I would have a try with `find . -type f -size 0` or something similar. If you want to limit to `*.box` files then do `find . -name '*.box' -type f -size 0`. If you want to see file information then you can pass it to `ls` with `find . -name '*.box' -type f -size 0 -exec ls -al "{}" \;`

Comment: Dear Patrick: Yes, the find is getting the box files with zero size. The issue is to get the partner files as well. Is there any means to pass the names found to a next iteration.
Find the names of empty box files  (this is done)--> save the names found in the first round (save to some kind of variable)-->  then use the saved name to find other file types.

Comment: @Dellu Yes, `find` was one possible entry point to the solution. @Freeman wrote you the solution in a nice way ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check this simple script,I used the `find` command to search for all empty `.box` files (`-type f -name "*.box" -size 0`) and then I deletes the empty `.box` files using the `-delete` flag, at the end it removes the corresponding `.gt.txt` and `.tif` files by executing the `rm` command within the `-exec` flag :

```
#!/bin/bash

#specifing the directory where the files are located
directory="/path/to/files"

#changing to the specified directory
cd "$directory" || exit

#find and delete empty .box files along with their partners
find . -type f -name "*.box" -size 0 -delete -exec sh -c 'rm -f "${1%.box}.gt.txt" "${1%.box}.tif"' sh {} \;
```

Comment: I love your solution! Well done! I was thinking about `basename "{}" .box` to get the filename without the extension but I didn't know about the `${1%.box}` solution! I'm just trying to understand why we have to put twice `sh` in the `-exec` command. If I remove the second `sh`, it effectively doesn't work. But why?

Comment: @PatrickJanser because the first `sh` is used to execute the shell command, and the second `sh` is the argument being passed to the command adn the second `sh` is necessary in this case because the shell command being executed includes a positional parameter (`$1`) that needs to be provided!

Comment: Thank you so much. That was exactly I was looking for. I spent days looking for application that can do this. IN the Mac, I was using Keyboard maestro to delete them one by one. When I moved to Ubuntu, I was totally out of luck. Absolutely amazing. I cannot thank you enough.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to do it:

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in File*.box; do
  [ -s "$f" ] && continue
  base=${f%.*}
  rm ${base}{.gt.txt,.tif,.box}
done
```

Or, as a one-liner:

```
for f in File*.box; do [ -s "$f" ] && continue ; rm  ${f%.*}{.gt.txt,.tif,.box}; done
```

Comment: Nice readable solution! But isn't `.box` missing in the list of file extensions to delete?

Comment: @PatrickJanser Yes, thanks. I'll add it in.

Comment: Dear Mark. The box and partner files are deleted only if the box is empty. This one seems to delete all box files and their partners. Can you confirm?

Comment: No, if the box file is non-empty, the second line (`[ -s $f ] && continue`) should skip the remainder of the loop where the deletions happen.

Comment: Great. I didn't understand that part. This is brilliant. Thank you. It looks like you guys enjoy the challenge. Can you ask a related issue with this one?

Comment: More than one question per question is generally frowned upon, but new questions (and answers) are free anyway, so maybe just ask a new one... adding a link to this one if it helps. Get the link by clicking `share` and copying.