# Delete a file if it lacks a duplicate (partner)

Tags: bash, awk, find

Given to the success of the question I posted here: [Find empty files and their duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77132326/find-empty-files-and-their-duplicates/77132937#77132937), thank you Freeman & Mark Setchell,  I am now encouraged to ask another related question. In this case, the challenge is to delete the file if it lacks a partner.

The text2image tool in Tesseract sometimes fails to produce .box files at all.

The files are supposed to appear as triplets, as follows:

- File1.box
- File1.gt.txt
- File1.tif
- File2.box
- File2.gt.txt
- File2.tif

But, when the tool fails to produce the box file, what I get is just the two partner files as follows.

- File3.gt.txt
- File3.tif

What I want is to delete those (gt.txt and .tif) files that lack the box partner.

I hope the description is clear.

Comment: See [ask] (and look at other questions that have been upvoted and answers for examples) for how to ask a question and https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting for how to format the sample input, expected output, and code from the required [mcve].

Comment: Thank you for the information. I will check the information.

Comment: What is the supposed outcome, if you have only a box and a tif file, but no txt file?

Comment: In practical terms, that doesn't happen because the tool (text2image) is producing box files out of txt and tif files. If the txt file doesn't exist, no box or image file can be produced.
The process of production in tesseract is  like this: 
Take lines of texts (which is provided by the user) --> create images (tif) out of them--> create box files by referring to the image and txt files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what you want ?

```
#!/bin/bash

#create an array to store the box file names
declare -A box_files

#iterate over the files in the directory and populate the box_files array
for file in *.box; do
    # Get the file name without extension
    file_name="${file%.*}"
    # Add the box file name to the array
    box_files["$file_name"]=1
done

#iterate over the files in the directory
for file in *.{tif,gt.txt}; do
    #get the file name without extension
    file_name="${file%.*}"

    #check if the file is a box file
    if [[ "$file" == *.box ]]; then
        continue # Skip box files
    fi

    #check if the corresponding box file exists in the array
    if [ "${box_files["$file_name"]}" != 1 ]; then
        #delete the files without a partner
        rm "$file"
        echo "Deleted $file"
    fi
done
```

Comment: The first one worked. Thank you so much dear @Freeman.

Comment: I should have tested this very carefully. Unfortunately, it exterminated all of my text files (even if they have partners).

Comment: Oh dear! I'm sorry to hear that. It would have been great if you had tested with a smaller amount of data beforehand. Is there anything I can assist you with now?

Comment: Yah, I should have tested it on a smaller set. Terrible mistake. And, there is no good file recovery tool in Ubuntu. Disk Drill has been a life saver  for me in cases like this, in the Mac. I am now doing it all over. Thank you for the help dear Freeman. It would be great if you can look at the script once more, and improve it if that is possible.

Comment: @Dellu Sure I will review it again and make the necessary improvements. Thank you for bringing this to my attention.

Answer (score 1):

Given this file tree (from your example):

```
tree .
.
├── File1.box
├── File1.gt.txt
├── File1.tif
├── File2.box
├── File2.gt.txt
├── File2.tif
├── File3.gt.txt
└── File3.tif
```

With Ruby (if all the files start with `File`) collect all files with the same basename and reject groups of 3:

```
ruby -e 'Dir.glob("File*").group_by{|fn| fn[/^[^.]*/]}.
    reject{|k,v| v.length>=3}.each{|k,v| puts v}'
```

You can also classify by extension:

```
ruby -e 'p Dir.glob("**/*.{tif,gt.txt,box}").group_by{|fn| fn[/^[^.]*/]}'
```

Prints:

```
{"File1"=>["File1.box", "File1.gt.txt", "File1.tif"], "File2"=>["File2.box", "File2.gt.txt", "File2.tif"], "File3"=>["File3.gt.txt", "File3.tif"]}
```

Or do a recursive glob:

```
ruby -e 'Dir.glob("**/*.{tif,gt.txt,box}").group_by{|fn| fn[/^[^.]*/]}.
    reject{|k,v| v.length>=3}.each{|k,v| puts v}'
```

With Python (and you can use the same globs shown above with Ruby):

```
python3 -c '
paths={}
from pathlib import Path 
for fn in Path(".").glob("File*"):
    key,*_=str(fn).partition(".")
    paths.setdefault(key, []).append(fn)

for v in [v for k,v in paths.items() if len(v)<3]:
    print("\n".join(map(str,v)))'
```

Both print:

```
File3.gt.txt
File3.tif
```

To DELETE the files:

Ruby:

```
ruby -e 'Dir.glob("File*").group_by{|fn| fn[/^[^.]*/]}.
    reject{|k,v| v.length>=3}.each{|k,v| v.each{|fn| File.delete(fn)}}'
```

Python:

```
python3 -c '
paths={}
from pathlib import Path 
for fn in Path(".").glob("File*"):
    key,*_=str(fn).partition(".")
    paths.setdefault(key, []).append(fn)

for v in [v for k,v in paths.items() if len(v)<3]:
    for fn in v:
        print(f"Deleting: {fn}")
        fn.unlink()'
```

Comment: Thank you. It would be great if you can add the deleting command as well (specially on the python script).

Comment: Thank you. The ruby script does it for me.